# Eclipse does not launch without sudo

Tags: fedora, sudo, eclipse

On my Fedora (Fedora 22 Workstation) system, I recently installed Eclipse (`sudo dnf install eclipse-platform`). However, I am unable to launch Eclipse without using `sudo`. I would prefer not to have to use `sudo` to launch Eclipse. I have already tried reinstalling it
.

Output if I use the command `eclipse`:

`(Eclipse:2709): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: The property GtkMisc:ypad is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.`

The above message does not show up if I use `sudo eclipse`.

I also tried `gksu-polkit eclipse` and got this output:

`/usr/bin/xauth:  file /home/<my_username>/.Xauthority does not exist
/usr/bin/xauth:  file /home/<my_username>/.Xauthority does not exist
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.`

In addition, when I run `gksu-polkit eclipse`, I get an Eclipse error window that says:

`The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to find its companion shared library.`

Comment: Can you show the results of `ls -lat eclipseFilename`?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 26 Aug 11 07:44 /bin/eclipse -> /usr/lib64/eclipse/eclipse

Comment: Can you change the ownership of the file to the appropriate user:group

Comment: Ok, I changed the ownership. Even after doing that, eclipse doesn't launch

Comment: Maybe root has a significant difference in `$PATH`?

Comment: $PATH for root is the same as for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work (sort of).

I was running my Fedora machine on a GNOME Desktop Environment which was using the Wayland window system. When I switched to X, it ended up working.